# Powershell can't set inner text of xmlelement

Tags: xml, powershell, sharepoint-2007

I try to make a script which would update a webpart in sharepoint, I've found some example, but i have an issue with xml which i have to pass to web part.

Just for a note, the powershell which i use is 1.0.

```
$xmlDoc = New-Object xml;                
$newXmlElement = $xmlDoc.CreateElement("HtmlContent");       
$newXmlElement.InnerText="SomeValue";
```

So this piece of script where it breaks, i get an error saying:

> Property 'InnerText' cannot be found on this object; make sure it
>   exists and is settable.

I really don't know why it doesn't work, anyone has any idea?

I try to execute this lines in Windows Powershell comman line, and when i try to set innertext, it throws me this red error message.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a way to do it, it seems that in PowerShell v1.0 the object System.Xml.XmlElement, doesn't have property like InnerText etc, so the way i did is following:

```
 $xmlDoc=New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument;             
 $xmlElement=$xmlDoc.CreateElement("HtmlElement"); 
 $xmlText = $xmlDoc.CreateTextNode($cewpNewContent)
 $xmlElement.AppendChild($xmlText);
```

I hope this could have been useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The error you get when you try to assign value to an existing element using dot notation is because dot notation accesses `XmlElement` of the `XmlNode` you are on. `XmlElement` does not have `InnerText` where `XmlNode` does.

**Example on how to create and assign value using InnerText**

```
$xmlDoc = New-Object xml;
$newXmlElement = $xmlDoc.CreateNode("element", "HtmlContent", "")
$newXmlElement.InnerText = "SomeValue"

$secondXmlElement = $xmlDoc.CreateNode("element", "HtmlContentChild", "")
$secondXmlElement.InnerText = "NewValue"

$newXmlElement.AppendChild($secondXmlElement)
$xmlDoc.AppendChild($newXmlElement)
```

---

**Example of loops and Node access**

```
foreach($node in $nodes) {
  if ($node.element -ne $null) {
    $node.element.InnerText = "this will throw error" # generates the error
    $node.element = "this is correct"                 # Correct way to add InnerText
  }
  else { 
    $elementToAdd = $xmlDoc.CreateNode("element", "element", "")
    $elementToAdd.InnerText = "This is correct"
    $node.AppendChild($elementToAdd)
  }
}
```

[XmlDocument.CreateNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createnode?view=netframework-4.8)

> Creates an XmlNode with the specified node type, Name, and NamespaceURI (NamespaceURI is null in your example).

[XmlNode.AppendChild(XmlNode)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_XmlNode_AppendChild_System_Xml_XmlNode_)

> Adds the specified node to the end of the list of child nodes, of this node

[XmlNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode?view=netframework-4.8)

[XmlElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement?view=netframework-4.8)